# Is it safe to delete images from var/urapidflow/import/images?

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1, magento-2-commerce, adobe-commerce

I'm trying to free up some space and that directory appears to be massive.

Answer (score 1):

These image files are used for importing products when migrating Magento 1 data to Magento 2 using RapidFlow Pro extension.

If you are sure your Magento 2 is completed migration from Magento 1, it is safe to delete these images.

Comment: Never had a magento 1 website.

Comment: You can run this command to know which modules using that image directory: `grep -r urapidflow /path/to/your/magento/root/directory`. If your magento root directory is /var/www/html, the command should be `grep -r urapidflow /var/www/html`